# Isomorphic quotient groups $\frac{G}{H} \cong \frac{G}{K}$ imply $H \cong K$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I know that given a group $G$ and two normal subgroups $H,K \subset G$ then it is **not true** that:

*"if $H \cong K$ then $ \frac{G}{H} \cong \frac{G}{K} $ (the counterexample is quite easy with products of cyclic groups) "*

My question is: Is the converse true?

i.e.

> Given that $\frac{G}{H} \cong \frac{G}{K}$ then $H \cong K$ ?

I feel that the answer is no, but I can't think of an example.

Comment: This has been answered in [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/40881/isomorphic-quotients-by-isomorphic-normal-subgroups?lq=1), within the question itself. For a variation, see [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/329191/if-g-n-and-h-n-are-isomorphic-does-it-imply-g-and-h-are-isomorphic).

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Let $$G = \mathbb Z/4\mathbb Z\times\mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z$$
and consider the subgroups
$$H = \mathbb Z/4\mathbb Z\times \{e\}\\K=\mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z\times\mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z$$

Then $$G/K\cong G/H\cong\mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z$$ but $H\not\cong K$.

Comment: How about if $H$ is normal in $G$ and another group $G'$ and $G/H \cong G'/H$. Is it true that $G\cong G'$?

Comment: No. Take $G = \mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z\times  \mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z$, $G'= \mathbb Z/4\mathbb Z$ and $H =  \mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z$.

Comment: But $H$ is not a Cartesian product.  How is $H$ a subgroup of $\mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z \times \mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z$?

Comment: The subgroup of elements of the form $ (a,0)$ is isomorphic to $H$.

Comment: So then $H$ is not really a subgroup of both $G$ and $G'$.

Comment: Usually, we say $H$ is a subgroup of $G$ if it is isomorphic to a subgroup of $G$.

Answer (score 6):

Take, for instance, $G=\mathbb Z/4\mathbb Z \times \mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z$, $H=\mathbb Z/4 \mathbb Z \times \mathbf 0$, and $K=\mathbb Z /2\mathbb Z \times \mathbb Z/2 \mathbb Z$, so that $G/K\cong G/H \cong \mathbb Z/2 \mathbb Z$.

Comment: The group $K$ should be written as $2\mathbf Z/4\mathbf Z \times \mathbf Z/2\mathbf Z$ to make it naturally be a subgroup of $G$.

Answer (score 4):

This is (also) not true. Let $G = \mathbf Z^{(\mathbf N)}$, $H = (0)$, and $K = \mathbf Z\cdot e_1$ (where $e_1 = (1, 0,\ldots)$). Then $G/K \cong G \cong G/(0)$, but $K \ne 0 = H$.

Comment: Excuse me, but $Z^{(N)}$ stands for?

Comment: It is the set of sequences compactly supported (stationary at $0$ sequences) whose coefficients are in $\mathbb{Z}$.